# APNS push not working, and not 'failing', after moving to EC2 instance

Tags: php, https, amazon-ec2, port, apple-push-notifications

So, I moved my application to an EC2 instance, and Apple Push Notification Service stopped working.  I'm using the same certificate, same script, same everything.

- I've opened port 2195 in the security group for the EC2 instance.
- from the EC2 intance, telnet gateway.push.apple.com 2195 works
- my script receives no errors... everything gets to the end, even fwrite returns true... yet, I receive no push.

Things to note.

- My EC2 instance is accessed via https where my old server was http, but since the script would be running locally, and has nothing to do with Apache, I don't see why this should matter.  But, perhaps it does, so I'm letting you know :D

My script:

```
$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);
$ssl = 'ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort;
$apns = stream_socket_client($ssl, $error, $errorString, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
if($apns == false){
    echo "Error: $errorString";
    return false;
}
$payload['aps'] = array('alert' => $message, 'badge'=>$badge, 'sound' => 'default');
$payload = json_encode($payload);

$apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $device_id)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
if(fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage)){
    return true;
}
return false;
```

I've checked all of my variables, they are set.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  This is driving me bonkers :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was giving a bad device id.  The databases were different, and I stored something poorly. :(